# Mouseover in map loop reactjs

Tags: javascript, reactjs

How to set hover for itself within map in Reactjs

```
  hoverOn = () => {
    this.setState({ hover: true});
  }
  hoverOff = () => { 
    this.setState({ hover: false });    
  }



    ...
    var components = posts.map((post, i) => (
    .....
        <span className={this.state.hover ? 'showtooltip':'hidetooltip'} onHover={this.hoverOn} onMouseOut={this.hoverOff} onClick={(e) => this.viewPost(post, e)}><i className="quickview-button"></i></span> 
    ......
    ));
```

Since I use setState, everytime I hover on `span` it reflects to all list data which returned from map loop.
How can I use hover to reflect on itself element?

Thank so much

Answer (score 2, accepted):

wrap this logic in a little Component:

```
class Foo extends React.Component {
  constructor(){
    this.state = { hover: false };
  }

  render(){
    return <span 
      { ...this.props }
      className={ this.state.hover ? 'showtooltip':'hidetooltip' } 
      onHover={ () => this.setState({ hover: true }) } 
      onMouseOut={ () => this.setState({ hover: false }) } 
    />;
  }
}
```

and use that Component:

```
...
var components = posts.map((post, i) => (
.....
    <Foo onClick={(e) => this.viewPost(post, e)}><i className="quickview-button"></i></Foo> 
......
));
```

Comment: Makes more sense

Comment: @Thomas. Thanks. It works well but I do not know why we need to add ...this.props in return?

Comment: @HaiTien because you add an `onClick` handler to the component, and you add `children` to the component. If you don't forward these properties from the `<Foo />` to the `<span />` then the span will be rendered empty and without click-handler

Answer (score 2):

You can make `hover` inside state an object `state = { hover: {} }` and set it with index `i` on events i.e. `this.setState({ hover: {...this.state.hover, i: true }});`.

Then pass `i` parameter into those methods`onHover={(i) => this.hoverOn(i)}`
And change className setup to `<span className={this.state.hover[i] ? 'showtooltip':'hidetooltip'}` (thanks to @kenny for noticing this)

Comment: And your element should be `<span className={this.state.hover[i] ? 'showtooltip':'hidetooltip'} .....`

Comment: This line `this.setState({ hover[i]: true });` show wrong syntax although I added to state `hover: {}`

Comment: make a new obj like `var dupHover = this.state.hover` and then `dupHover[i] = true` and finally `this.setState({hover: dupHover})`

Comment: @Kenny, @hai-tien, sorry, yes I just edited it, you can set state like this:  `this.setState({ hover: {...this.state.hover, i: true }});` - generic approach I think. I guess you can't hover more than one element at a time, so it could be just a new object with `{i: true}`